# Installing SharePoint 2013 on Linux [Myth or truth]

Tags: 2013, installation, linux

Some friends told me that SharePoint beta 2013 can be installed on Linux.
I replied that it is not possible as SharePoint 2013 requires IIS, but they kept affirming it can.

Has anyone actually tried to install SharePoint 2013 on Linux?

Comment: Dual booting is hardly 'running on linux'

Comment: someone told me that, its not what I am stating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 can only be installed on 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or Windows Server 2012.

You can have the interface for a SharePoint App running on any kind of Web server (including Linux) but this is always external to SharePoint.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has made sure that Sharepoint won't work in WINE.

WINE developers cannot make the BITS service and other services that Sharepoint and other programs need.

I tried the Sharepoint 2013 beta under the current WINE, it complains that it is not Windows 2008 R2 even if you set it for Windows 2008 emulation. Microsoft has a way to get past the WINE emulation of Windows versions.

Microsoft does this on purpose as a Linux Server with WINE costs nothing, but the Windows 2008/2012 Server licenses costs thousands per user. Do you really think they will allow Linux/WINE to run their Sharepoint software? It won't even run SQL Server or Exchange Server.

There are no Linux alternatives to Sharepoint yet, Microsoft still has their monopoly for now.

2013 might be the year of The Linux Rebellion for video game players, but not Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I havent tried but, to say its impossible? no.... its possible by having layers that except .net and getting IIS installed or an IIS equivilent i guess.

But the issue is not having any support if anything goes wrong later down the line if you do get it up and running.

To answer your question it is possible but wouldnt run properly!

to get asp.net running
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

maybe run IIS on WINE but mono is better solution.

Comment: Prove it..... :)

Comment: Jesus! Really “almost” a master. OMG!

Comment: why the omg, dont diss it until youv tried it ;) , have you tried running linux on a vpc and having iis (mono) running on it,.... I did say it is possible but why do it when nothing is supported and if you did get it working there would be so much complications along the way and comming up ;) , nothing is impossible :)

Comment: Good luck trying to get owssvr.dll working on Wine.